# getSerializableExtra and getParcelableExtra are deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, deprecation-warning, android-tiramisu

I have upgraded `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to `33`.

I am now getting warnings telling me that the [getSerializableExtra(name:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)) and [getParcelableExtra(name:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String)) methods are deprecated.

I checked and confirmed from the documentation in the [Intent](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/t-beta2-incr/changes/android.content.Intent) class that these two methods are indeed deprecated.

The documentation suggests that I use the new [getSerializableExtra(name:clazz:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) and [getParcelableExtra(name:clazz:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) methods instead.

Can anyone can help me use the new methods?

#### Example warnings

1. Warning while getting an `Object`:

[image: getSerializableExtra_Deprecated_Image]

2. Warning while getting a `List` or `ArrayList`:

[image: getSerializableExtra_Deprecated_List_Image]

Comment: intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("yourintentkey",MyPOJOClass::class.java) as ArrayList<MyPOJOClass>

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is what I use:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Serializable> Bundle.serializable(key: String): T? = when {
  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU -> getSerializable(key, T::class.java)
  else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getSerializable(key) as? T
}

inline fun <reified T : Serializable> Intent.serializable(key: String): T? = when {
  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU -> getSerializableExtra(key, T::class.java)
  else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getSerializableExtra(key) as? T
}
```

I've also written the same for [getParcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73311814/1979703) here and requested this to be added to the [Support libraries directly](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242048899)

Comment: How can we get `ArrayList` from intent?

Comment: That's not what you asked in your original question

Comment: Okay man, the question is updated.

Comment: @Niklas You should use Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU instead of 33. Also, here's a request on the issue tracker to offer this (and the Parcelable one) on the support library: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243986223

Comment: I personally prefer the integer variable as I get super confused with their code names. Both work fine :)

Comment: Any update one How can do this with ArrayList ? @Niklas

Comment: @MaulikTogadiya that's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73019160/android-getparcelableextra-deprecated/73311814#73311814

Answer (score 23):

method `T getSerializableExtra(String, Class<T>)` is introduced from android 33.
so you shoud use an if block for devices using android below 33.

```
fun <T : Serializable?> getSerializable(activity: Activity, name: String, clazz: Class<T>): T
{
    return if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
               activity.intent.getSerializableExtra(name, clazz)!!
           else
               activity.intent.getSerializableExtra(name) as T
}
```

and then you can use it in your activity like this:

```
val myPOJOClass = getSerializable(this, "my_intent_key", MyPOJOClass::class.java)
```

Comment: Anyway, even after the Version check, the annoying hint that the method is deprecated still does not allow you to sleep peacefully :)

Comment: This works fine. But how can we get `ArrayList` from intent?

Comment: @RumitPatel, you can use `getParcelableArrayList( "key", MyListItem.class )`. There is a wrong reference in the Javadoc pointing to `getParcelable( String, Class )` instead.

Comment: Consider not using the double bang, but making the function nullable.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re I agree, because if the value was not found for some reason, you will get an NPE

Comment: @neronovs, you can add `@Suppress("DEPRECATION")` before calling the deprecated method to get sleep peacefully :)

Answer (score 6):

However, [Mohamad Seyedi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73003770/2289835) answer did the job. But it fails in the case of getting intent data from **`onActivityResult()`**.

We can't get data using Activity's intent inside **`onActivityResult()`**. Below are the solutions I got.

**Solution 1: Using extension function:**

```
fun <T : Serializable?> Intent.getSerializable(key: String, m_class: Class<T>): T {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        this.getSerializableExtra(key, m_class)!!
    else
        this.getSerializableExtra(key) as T
}
```

**Usage:**

```
val myPOJOClass = intent.getSerializable("my_intent_key", MyPOJOClass::class.java)
```

---

**Solution 2: Using regular function:**

```
fun <T : Serializable?> getSerializable(intent: Intent, key: String, m_class: Class<T>): T {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        intent.getSerializableExtra(key, m_class)!!
    else
        intent.getSerializableExtra(key) as T
}
```

**Usage:**

```
val myPOJOClass = getSerializable(intent, "my_intent_key", MyPOJOClass::class.java)
```

Answer (score 5):

For those of us who still use Java, this function does the trick:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "deprecation"})
@Nullable
public static <T extends Serializable> T getSerializable(@Nullable Bundle bundle, @Nullable String key, @NonNull Class<T> clazz) {
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            return bundle.getSerializable(key, clazz);
        } else {
            try {
                return (T) bundle.getSerializable(key);
            } catch (Throwable ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding upon [Rumit Patel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73469967/3991578), using an inline function with reified type parameter, usage is even simpler.
Note that I made the return type nullable, because `!!` should in my opinion only be used as a last resort (or at caller side).

```kotlin
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
inline fun <reified T : Serializable> Intent.getSerializable(key: String): T? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        this.getSerializableExtra(key, T::class.java)
    else
        this.getSerializableExtra(key) as? T
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Intent.getParcelable(key: String): T? {
    Timber.d("intentextras parce")
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        this.getParcelableExtra(key, T::class.java)
    } else {
        this.getParcelableExtra(key)
    }
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Intent.getParcelableArrayList(key: String): ArrayList<T>? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        this.getParcelableArrayListExtra(key, T::class.java)
    } else {
        this.getParcelableArrayListExtra(key)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val mode1: Mode = intent.getSerializable("key")
val mode2 = intent.getSerializable<Mode>("key")
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Mohamad's answer, you can do an extension

```
fun <T : Serializable?> Bundle.getSerializableCompat(key: String, clazz: Class<T>): T {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) getSerializable(key, clazz)!! else (getSerializable(key) as T)
}
```

and call it everywhere like this:

```
   arguments?.getSerializableCompat("my_key", MyClass::class.java)
```

Comment: I line the naming you chose compared to the other answers. Then you can keep a consistent naming pattern between similar extensions on Bundle, Intent, etc. You don't need to pass in clazz if you use reified like other answers here

Answer (score 1):

```
val myPojoClass = getSerializable(intent, "key_name_here", MyPojoTypeClass::class.java)
```

then, create that function

```
 private fun <T : Serializable?> getSerializable(intent: Intent, key: String, className: Class<T>): T {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33)
            intent.getSerializableExtra(key, className)!!
        else
            intent.getSerializableExtra(key) as T
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used it myself till yet .
As the doc says the updated method is

`T getSerializableExtra(String, Class<T>)` So you can use it as follows i think.

```
val myPOJOClass = intent.getSerializableExtra("my_intent_key", MyPOJOClass::class.java)
```

Comment: Let me check that out.

Comment: this method only works for android 33 and above. if you use it in devices using android < 33, you will receive a crash...

Comment: That's pretty obvious since its been  added  in 33 . you have to put a version check ..

Comment: This works fine. But how can we get ArrayList from intent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use top functions to serialize arguments

but I had a problem serializing the List of object

You can use this way to put and get serialized argument data

Because List is not a Serializable Class, you need to convert it to Array List that supports serializable

These functions are used for serializable

```
 inline fun <reified T : Serializable> Bundle.serializable(key: String): T? = 
     when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU -> 
            getSerializable(key, T::class.java)
        else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getSerializable(key) as? T
     }

inline fun <reified T : Serializable> Intent.serializable(key: String): T? = 
    when {
       Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU -> 
           getSerializableExtra(key, T::class.java)
       else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getSerializableExtra(key) as? T
    }
```

and this way handle puts serialized List of objects

```
  class YourFragment: Fragment {

      private latinit var list: List<YourObject>


      fun newInstance(
           listOfYourObject: List<YourObject>
       ): YourFragment {

           val args = Bundle()
           val yourList= ArrayList<YourObject>()
           yourList.addAll(listOfYourObject)
           args.putSerializable(LIST_KEY, yourList)
        
           val fragment = YourFragment()
           fragment.arguments = args
           return fragment
       }

   }
```

and now can get serialize of your list object in this way

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    requireArguments().serializable<ArrayList<YourObject>>(LIST_KEY)?.let{
        list = it.toList()
    }
   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we already have good answers with Serializable, will answer in favour of Parcelable

If you feel ***BundleComapt*** and ***IntentCompat*** versions are longer you can create extensions like this and use

```
inline fun <reified T: Parcelable> Bundle.getParcel(key: String): T? =
    BundleCompat.getParcelable(this, key, T::class.java)

inline fun <reified T: Parcelable> Intent.getParcel(key: String): T? =
    IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra(this, key, T::class.java)
```