# The getParcelableExtra method is deprecated

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I am passing [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) data into an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) and getting it out on the other end using the [getParcelableExtra(name:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String)) method. However, [getParcelableExtra(name:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String)) seems to be deprecated. How do I fix the deprecation warning? Alternatively, are there any other options for doing this? I am using a `compileSdkVersion` value of 33.

##### Code snippet

```
var data = intent.getParcelableExtra("data")
```

Comment: Hi Dear @RabindraKhadka, you should consider adding more `details` like sample `code` to help us fully understand your issue.

Comment: Hi @GedFlod, I have added some code snippet.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Here are two extension methods that I use for `Bundle` & `Intent`:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Intent.parcelable(key: String): T? = when {
  SDK_INT >= 33 -> getParcelableExtra(key, T::class.java)
  else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getParcelableExtra(key) as? T
}

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Bundle.parcelable(key: String): T? = when {
  SDK_INT >= 33 -> getParcelable(key, T::class.java)
  else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getParcelable(key) as? T
}
```

I also [requested this to be added to the support library](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242048899)

And if you need the ArrayList support there is:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Bundle.parcelableArrayList(key: String): ArrayList<T>? = when {
  SDK_INT >= 33 -> getParcelableArrayList(key, T::class.java)
  else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getParcelableArrayList(key)
}

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Intent.parcelableArrayList(key: String): ArrayList<T>? = when {
  SDK_INT >= 33 -> getParcelableArrayListExtra(key, T::class.java)
  else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getParcelableArrayListExtra(key)
}
```

Note: There are [some issues on SDK 33](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585930) with the new methods, so you might only want to use it starting from SDK 34.

Comment: Good solution. Requested here to be part of the android-x: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243986223

Comment: I've requested this myself. I've updated the description to include the ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242048899

Comment: Wait, did I miss it, or you've added it after I wrote it?

Comment: I've created the feature request myself on August 10th after answering this question here and edited my original answer with my link after you wrote your comment. (So that others can see it directly)

Comment: So I didn't miss it. BTW, I think the same exists for getSerializableExtra, too. Maybe for others as well.

Comment: Good point. There already exists a question for that so I answered there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73543350/1979703

Comment: Do you know how to do it for getParcelableArrayListExtra and getParcelableArrayList ? For some reason when I try something similar to what's here, it fails to build...

Comment: @androiddeveloper updated my answer to include ArrayList support.

Comment: It returns List instead of ArrayList. This might be the reason I failed. How come it returns a List? Both functions instead are supposed to return ArrayList. Also, BTW, I think you have the wrong name inside one of them.

Comment: @androiddeveloper good call. Now it's updated :)

Comment: Seems perfect now! Thank you. How did you know how to change it properly? I always make mistakes with this kind of thing... Also, do you know how such a thing can be called from Java? It seems like it's impossible to reach such functions...

Comment: @androiddeveloper I've worked a lot with generics in Kotlin, so I know about `reified` and what I can use. It just takes tome. This only works in Kotlin due to `reified` which only works in `inline fun`. There's no such thing in Java.

Comment: I didn't mean "how to implement it on Java?". I mean "In some Java classes, how can I reach the functions you've declared here?"

Comment: You can't. Convert your other classes to use Kotlin :)

Comment: So I need to implement something similar, and have duplicates? Too bad.

Comment: It seems there is a bug on Android 13 related to this API. Google says they will fix it on the next version and provide something too. So, for now, I think it's better to use `> VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU` instead of `>= VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU` . Link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585930#comment6

Comment: Does this code work for getSerializableExtra also ?

Comment: Agreed with @androiddeveloper to use `> VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU`, I too encountered an NPE when attempting to access the parcelable on Android 13. Looking at the `IntentCompat` implementation for the `core-ktx` library, it looks like they're checking for "at least U", so it's also `> VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU`. Kinda an egregious miss here to deprecate for Android 13 when they should've been deprecating for 14+. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/b0895cf4dc9a13b63d3d47aeb7b07a99cfc0bd28/core/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/content/IntentCompat.java#211

Comment: I applied this solution but there is generate too many crashes in firebase from users. Do you have any other solution for this? suggest me please.

Comment: Check out my latest edit, you probably should only use it on SDK >= 34

Comment: I would suggest to rename it to `getCompatParcelable` since it tries to be compatible with the whole Android's versions.

Comment: No more valid solution. Now there is BundleCompat, see solution below

Comment: Some Samsung devices with API 33 crashes with this solution. I suggest using IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra solution.

Comment: Got the crashes on firebase only on devices with Android.Tiramisu by using check for >= TIRAMISU only. So I would suggest using IntentCompat or BundleCompat as in below answers.

Answer (score 44):

[Now we need to use `getParcelableExtra()` with the type-safer class added to API 33](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E))

SAMPLE CODE For kotlin

```
val userData = if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
  intent.getParcelableExtra("DATA", User::class.java)
} else {
  intent.getParcelableExtra<User>("DATA")
}
```

SAMPLE CODE For JAVA

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
  user = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data", User.class);
} else {
  user = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
}
```

Comment: I cannot make this work in Java... Could you please indicate to me what should I put instead of `User::class.java`? My code is `mediaButtonEvent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);`

Comment: @LuisA.Florit i have updated my answer please check

Comment: Thanks @AskNilesh. In the second one you meant "SAMPLE CODE For Java". In my case, it would be `KeyEvent.class` instead of `User.class`.

Answer (score 44):

[androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.10.0) provides two classes `IntentCompat` and `BundleCompat` with few helpful static methods

`androidx.core.os.BundleCompat`:

```
BundleCompat.getParcelable(Bundle, String, Class<T>)
BundleCompat.getParcelableArray(Bundle, String, Class<? extends Parcelable>): Parcelable[] 
BundleCompat.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle, String, Class<? extends T> clazz): ArrayList<T>
BundleCompat.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle, String, Class<? extends T>): SparseArray<T>
```

`androidx.core.content.IntentCompat`

```
IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra(Intent, String, Class<T>)
IntentCompat.getParcelableArrayExtra(Intent, String, Class<? extends Parcelable>): Parcelable[]
IntentCompat.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent, String, Class<? extends T>): ArrayList<T>
```

Example for retrieving an object of `android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice`:

```
IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra(intent, BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, BluetoothDevice::class.java)
```

Simplified version of extensions proposed by @Niklas:

```
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Bundle.parcelable(key: String): T? =
    BundleCompat.getParcelable(this, key, T::class.java)

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Intent.parcelable(key: String): T? =
    IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra(this, key, T::class.java)
```

For ArrayList:

```
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Bundle.parcelableList(key: String): List<T>? =
    BundleCompat.getParcelableArrayList(this, key, T::class.java)

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Intent.parcelableList(key: String): List<T>? =
    IntentCompat.getParcelableArrayListExtra(this, key, T::class.java)
```

Comment: Using the compat classes seems like the right answer here.

Comment: For bundle: `BundleCompat.getParcelable`

Comment: in addition to @dees91 , for a list of object `BundleCompat.getParcelableArrayList(requireArguments(),"key",YourObjectClassName::class.java)`

Answer (score 8):

For example, in Java:

```
UsbDevice device;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.S_V2) { // TIRAMISU onwards
    device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE, UsbDevice.class);
} else {
    device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
}
```

This still requires `@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "RedundantSuppression"})`.

Comment: It must be `TIRAMISU` (33) instead of `S_V2` (32)

Comment: @MBH no. Above code is correct. It can be `SDK_INT > S_V2` (greater than 32) or `SDK_INT >= TIRAMISU` (greater than or equal to 33).

Comment: The operator `>` suffices, because equal values are irrelevant anyway. Haven't benchmarked on JVM, but there may also be a small performance implication with the choice of operator (it doesn't matter with one iteration only): https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763604/549372

Comment: @Boken yeah you are right! my fault :) I always prefer putting the related sdk instead of  the previous one

Answer (score 7):

As described in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)), `getParcelableExtra` was deprecated in API level 33.

So check if the API LEVEL  is >= 33 or change the method,

```java
...

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) { // TIRAMISU
    data = intent.getParcelableExtra (String name, Class<T> clazz)
}else{
    data = intent.getParcelableExtra("")
}
```

---

Here is an example using android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice

```java
...
val device = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33){ // TIRAMISU
    intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
        BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME,
        BluetoothDevice::class.java
    )
}else{
    intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what did you mean here. `getParcelableExtra (String name, Class<T> clazz)` makes no sense.

Comment: See the sample code I added.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did something like that:  `KeyEvent event = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 33) ? mediaButtonEvent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT) : mediaButtonEvent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, KeyEvent.class);`