# The getParcelableExtra method is deprecated in Android Studio

Tags: android

Here is my Code for a broadcast receiver

```
private val bReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if(intent?.action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND){
            val device = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
            val list = mutableSetOf<ListItem>()
            list.addAll(discoveryAdapter.currentList)
            if(device != null) list.add(ListItem(device, false))
            discoveryAdapter.submitList(list.toList())
            binding.tvEmptySearch.visibility = if(list.isEmpty()) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            try{
                Log.d("MyLog", "Device: ${device?.name}")
            } catch (e: SecurityException){

            }
        } else if(intent?.action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED){
            getPairedDevices()
        } else if(intent?.action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED){
            binding.imBluetoothSearch.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.pbSearch.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}`
```

`your text`

The getParcelableExtra method is deprecated. How can I upgrade?

Comment: This may solve your issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75824124/14187529