# getParcelableArrayListExtra deprecated what is the alternative?

Tags: android, kotlin, deprecation-warning, android-tiramisu

I have upgraded `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 33.

Now I am getting this warning [image]

```
val picList =
           result.data?.getParcelableArrayListExtra<PageNumberFile>(KEY_CAM_PIC_LIST)
```

It suggest me use Use the type-safer, What is the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getSerializableExtra and getParcelableExtra deprecated, What is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72571804/getserializableextra-and-getparcelableextra-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Answer (score 2):

Your best guide would be [DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String))

> This method was deprecated in `API Level 33`.
> Use the type-safer `getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)` starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES#TIRAMISU.

so you should use [THIS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20T%3E)) `getParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, Class<? extends T> clazz)`. Note second argument, in your case it should be `PageNumberFile::class.java`

PS. I would post working snippet/line, but you have posted code as image and I can't copy it for improving and pasting in my answer and I won't be rewritting this, too lazy. Don't ever post text as not-copyable image!

Comment: thanks, From where I can find out all deprecated android code in Tiramisu and code that is added in this version?

Comment: yes, you ma introduce some `if` for OS version, on older, below Tiramisu, you may still safely use old way/method

Answer (score 0):

[androidx.core:core-ktx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) provides `IntentCompat` and `androidx.core.os.BundleCompat` class, with the following method:

```
IntentCompat.getParcelableArrayListExtra(result.data, KEY_CAM_PIC_LIST, PageNumberFile::class.java)
```

To make it more convenient, you can create extensions:

```
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Bundle.parcelableList(key: String): List<T>? =
    BundleCompat.getParcelableArrayList(this, key, T::class.java)

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Intent.parcelableList(key: String): List<T>? =
    IntentCompat.getParcelableArrayListExtra(this, key, T::class.java)
```